# Finding negative values in tuple of list in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, tuples

I have tuple of list as below.

```
listt = [('1995', 0.2),
         ('1996', 0.05),
         ('1997', 0.029),
         ('1998', 0.43,
         ('1999', -0.086),
         ('2000', 0.050,
         ('2001', -0.27),
         ('2002', 0.173),
         ('2003', 0.289)]
```

Here, 1999 and 2001 have negative values. I need to print years of negative values. I wrote below code but it doesnt work.

```
print(filter(listt, key=lambda x:x[1]<0)[0]))
```

Comment: You have unclosed tuples in that list.

Comment: That code has syntax errors and doesn't run at all.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: What documentation says that `filter` has a `key` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` will run a given function over all the elements of the list and returns only those elements for which the function returns `True`. so it should be:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1]<0, listt))
```

Output:

```
[('1999', -0.086), ('2001', -0.27)]
```

Since you only want to print the corresponding years then you can enumerate and print them

```
[y for y, v in filter(lambda x: x[1]<0, listt)]
```

Output:

```
['1999', '2001']
```

Or instead do both in one shot:

```
[y for y, v in listt if v < 0]
```

Output:

```
['1999', '2001']
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to do it:

```
print([k for k, v in listt if v < 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
listt = [('1995', 0.2),
     ('1996', 0.05),
     ('1997', 0.029),
     ('1998', 0.43),
     ('1999', -0.086),
     ('2000', 0.050),
     ('2001', -0.27),
     ('2002', 0.173),
     ('2003', 0.289)]

print([x[0] for x in listt if x[1] < 0]) #=>['1999', '2001']
```